# dynamic slug with permanent redirect or store slug on database

Tags: python, django, seo, slug

Which is the best option for urls on a news page:

Dynamically generate slugs. Load the page from the object id. If the slug doesn't match, permanent redirect to the correct slug.

```
myweb.com/542/my-news-item
```

Cons i see: If the news title is changed the slug changes, but the old slug will redirect to the new one, so i dont know if it is a problem for lookups.

OR:

Static slug that will never change, even if the news title is changed.

```
myweb.com/my-news-item
```

Cons i see: One more field on the db. If i change the news title radically, the slug will be very different

Comment: not related to main issue, but you can change the news title without changing the slug by doing something like `if not self.id : self.slug = slugify(self.title)`, usually by overriding save method

Answer (score 1):

If you want slugs to update, without breaking the old urls, you could separate slugs and link the latest in your list views, something along these lines should do it:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField() # etc

class ArticleSlug(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    date_created = models.DateTime(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        get_latest_by = "date_created"
```

In your enlisting template you could simply call the latest slug, but you'll probably want to have some M/Y/D hierarchy in the urls aswell

```
<a href="/news/articles/{{ article.articleslug_set.latest }}/">{{ article.title }}</a>
```

If your site gets a lot of traffic, you might want to add a celery task that retrieves the latest slug and copies it to a field on your article model now and then. That will save you some SQL JOINs.

Answer (score 0):

How about a combination of using the [redirects app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/redirects/?from=olddocs/) and a post save signal like what this [guy wrote](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3atYuN6SZqYRUJ%3atimmyomahony.com/blog/2012/10/22/create-automatic-redirects-upon-changing-url-dependent-field-your-django-models/%20&cd=13&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=sg).